# Beginner wants app recommendation for making electronic music

Tags: recording, beginner, tempo

I make mathematical pictures and want to back them with some music of my own composition. I play no instruments besides doodling with pianos. Actually, if I could get an app that would record my doodlings pitch-by-pitch and play them back in piano I’d be happy.

I tried this on an app that gave me a shortened piano keyboard for input, and I hit the record key, but the playback wasn’t what I put in because the timing of my key presses were completely ignored. It all came out very robotic.

I’d like to put in a series of <100 notes, and have that recorded at exactly the timing I used in the input. And then put that or portions or distortions of that on repeat. Can it be done? Thx.

P.S. (In response to the responses) I don’t have access to a real keyboard.

Comment: Do you want app playback or just music recordings? What prevents you from videotaping yourself on the keyboard with the default camera app?

Comment: Please read about [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But plenty such solutions exist; a few minutes research should find one. And why does it need to be an app? Why not a digital keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to learn some scripting language like Python. You can see an image basically like a 2d matrix, in which each cell has 3 values, RGB.

You can parse the image via Python, get the data, perform processing you like (that's the artistic part I think) and then generate a MIDI file with music.

In this way the music will be somehow linked to the images.